# How to show the text from the right to left in the Appery.io app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, appery.io

I have created an app on the Appery.io app builder and i need to show the text from the left side to the right. How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Appery.io apps are Cordova-based, so you can use a simple CSS property "direction" for that direction:rtl.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction